# Django - Are model save() methods lazy?

Tags: database, django, django-models, save

Are model save() methods lazy in django?

For instance, at what line in the following code sample will django hit the database?

```
my_model = MyModel()
my_model.name = 'Jeff Atwood'
my_model.save()
# Some code that is independent of my_model...
model_id = model_instance.id
print (model_id)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not make much sense to have a lazy save, does it? Django's [`QuerySets`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#id3) are lazy, the model's `save` method is not.

From the django source:

`django/db/models/base.py`, lines 424–437:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
    """
    Saves the current instance. Override this in a subclass if you want to
    control the saving process.

    The 'force_insert' and 'force_update' parameters can be used to insist
    that the "save" must be an SQL insert or update (or equivalent for
    non-SQL backends), respectively. Normally, they should not be set.
    """
    if force_insert and force_update:
        raise ValueError("Cannot force both insert and updating in \
            model saving.")
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, 
        force_update=force_update)

save.alters_data = True
```

Then, `save_base` does the heavy lifting (same file, lines 439–545):

```
...
transaction.commit_unless_managed(using=using)
...
```

And in `django/db/transaction.py`, lines 167–178, you'll find:

```
def commit_unless_managed(using=None):
    """
    Commits changes if the system is not in managed transaction mode.
    """
    ...
```

---

P.S. All line numbers apply to django version `(1, 3, 0, 'alpha', 0)`.

Comment: Actually, in some cases lazy saves would be preferable. Lazy saves would enable much shorter transactions without any effort on the programmer's side. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215833/django-keeping-save-based-transactions-short

Comment: Agreed, good answer, but yes sometimes it makes a lot of sense to have a lazy save.